# Can *he* in Rev. 19:13 be identified as Christ without using "The Word of God" for the identification?

Tags: john, revelation, new-testament, christology

Can *he* in Rev. 19:13 be identified as Christ without using "The Word of God" (ὁ λόγος τοῦ θεοῦ) for the identification?

> He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is called is The Word of God
> (Rev. 19:13, ESV)

If we can identify the one riding the white horse in this passage as Christ, this is more evidence that ὁ λόγος in John 1:1 is Christ.  What is the evidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pertinent passage in Rev 19:11-16 says this, set out to display its structure:

Then I saw heaven standing open, and there before me was a white horse. And **its rider is called Faithful and True.**

- With righteousness **He** judges and wages war.
- **He** has eyes like blazing fire, and many royal crowns on **His** head.
- **He** has a name written on **Him** that only **He** **Himself** knows.
- **He** is dressed in a robe dipped in blood,
- and **His** name is The Word of God.
- The armies of heaven, dressed in fine linen, white and pure, follow **Him** on white horses.
- And from **His** mouth proceeds a sharp sword with which to strike down the nations,
- and **He** will rule them with an iron scepter.
- **He** treads the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God the Almighty.
- And **He** has a name written on His robe and on His thigh: "KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS."

Note the simple structure of the passage - all the pronouns (explicit and implied) refer back to V11 and the "rider on the white horse".

OK, that is almost the easy part.  Now for the slightly more demanding exegetical part - who is the rider on the white horse called "faithful and true"?.

"Faithful and True" is a title of Jesus as shown in Rev 3:14 -

> “To the angel of the church in Laodicea write: These are the words of
> the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the ruler of God’s creation.

Thus, the highly symbolic picture in Rev 19:11-16 is of Jesus as the great conquering hero who leads the armies of heaven.  This is confirmed by:

- the "eyes like blazing fire" also taken from Rev 1:14
- the rob dipped in blood referring to Jesus' sacrifice (see Rev 5)
- the sharp two-edged sword from the moth as described in Rev 1:15
- the presence of the "iron scepter" compare Jesus' description in Rev 2:27, 12:5
- Jesus is to rule all nations as per Rev 11:15-18.

Thus, Jesus is portrayed in Rev 19 as the conquering leader who is also KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS, who other title is "The Word of God".

Comment: also Psalm 2.7-9 is being referenced, which is clearly about the son.

Comment: @Robert - agreed - but wanted to stay with undisputed comments from the same book of Revelation.

Comment: Technically, it is not Jesus. The spiritual entity that is "The Word of God" and eventually was manifested in the flesh as Jesus Christ, then went back to being that spiritual entity, who had a different name before he became "The Christ". It stands to reason, therefore, that when he went back to being that spiritual entity, he would have taken back that name.